# Square root Taylor series

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to verify the inequality:
$$
\sqrt{n+k} - \sqrt{n} \leq \frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}. 
$$
I can Taylor expand roughly, but I would like to make this rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}

where the last inequality is due to $\sqrt{n+k}$ is positive and $k>0$.